# How do I create a custom application for Virtual Windows XP in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, virtualization

When you install a program in Virtual XP it becomes available in the Windows 7 start menu like so:

```
Program Name (Virtual Windows XP)
```

**How do I create a custom application in this fashion so that I can access an XP system application like Command Prompt or Windows Explorer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy a shortcut within the Virtual Windows XP machine into the All Users Start Menu, those shortcuts will show up in the host Windows 7 Start Menu